# SSH permissions error when cloning github

Tags: ssh, permissions

When I use Windows PowerShell to try to clone a github repo, it throws this error:

`Cloning into 'repo-name'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Does anyone know how to fix this ssh permissions error? I've tried looking and I haven't seen a step-by-step guide on fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this doc and follow step by step.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: When I try to follow the steps in that doc, It gives me this error:

bash: shh-agent: command not found

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I use Windows for my OS